# Obejct is Jquery after ajax call is giving null

Tags: jquery, ajax, object, null, this

I am giving a call with click, and this will go to server call.

```
$(this).click(function(){
   alert($(this).html()); //this is giving value
   var urlLink = someURL;
   var data = "id=" + "123";
   $.ajax({
        url : urlLink,
    data : data,
    cache: false,
    success : function(resp) {
      alert($(this).html()); //this is giving null
    }
   });
});
```

Once after success, if i alert the same giving null. could any once please give an idea, what's going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> The this reference within all
>   callbacks is the object in the context
>   option passed to $.ajax in the
>   settings; if context is not specified,
>   this is a reference to the Ajax
>   settings themselves.

Either set the `context` option of the ajax object, or save the object in a variable outside the scope of the callback function.

```
$(this).click(function(){
   var $obj = $(this);
   alert($obj.html()); //this is giving value
   var urlLink = someURL;
   var data = "id=" + "123";
   $.ajax({
        url : urlLink,
    data : data,
    cache: false,
    success : function(resp) {
      alert($obj.html()); //this will give you the value too
    }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all the scope of the `$(this)` statement in your `success` function relates to the data returned from the AJAX call.

Your first `$(this)` statement refers to the element which was clicked on.

Try changing the success cal to the below to see the returned data alerted:

```
success : function(resp) {
    alert(resp);
}
```

If this still shows an empty value there may be an underlying issue with the code executed on the server-side of the AJAX call.